# How to query a grid with a boundary that wraps around the bounds of the grid

Tags: c#, grid

Using C# I'm trying to find if a a particular cell (marked as a green X below) is within the boundary of another cell (marked as a blue X below). But the boundary needs to loop around if it goes off any of the edges. In this example the boundary is 1 cell wide but it could be bigger, as could the size of the grid as a whole.

[image: a]

```
int greenX = 1;
int greenY = 1;

int blueX = 4;
int blueY = 4;

int boundarySize = 1;

if (greenX >= (blueX - boundarySize) && 
    greenX <= (blueX + boundarySize) && 
    greenY >= (blueY - boundarySize) && 
    greenY <= (blueY + boundarySize))
{
   // Within Boundary
}
```

The code I have works as long as no part of the boundary goes over the edge. This is probably a simple problem but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I changed the title to something that I think is better.  Feel free to change it if you don't like it, but keep in mind that you don't need to put tags like "C#" in the titles.

Comment: You have to do a *hittest* for each point of green `X` with each point of blue `X`.

Comment: What is a hittest? I've never heard of it.